# I can't retrieve data from my API using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have create an API using NodeJS, I am trying to retrieve data from the API using AngularJS however I can not output any data.

Here is my API. As you can see the data is in JSON format. A live link to my [API](https://forgetthis-jafar70.c9users.io/)

```
{"status":"success","data":[{"_id":"58175cb6f0c48b2b9821d799","listen_url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSbZidsgMfw","image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/41/Yonkers_tyler_cover.jpg/220px-Yonkers_tyler_cover.jpg","producers":"Tyler, The Creator","label":"XL Recordings","artist":"Tyler, The Creator","song_title":"Yonkers ","__v":0},{"_id":"581760e7aa7eb70a8cf0d770","listen_url":"https://vimeo.com/179791907","image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2a/Frank_Ocean_Blonde_2.jpg","producers":"Frank Ocean & Om'Mas Keith","label":"Boys Don't Cry","artist":"Frank Ocean","song_title":"Nikes","__v":0},{"_id":"582199b38e7a590871b38893","listen_url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4pon-hdEXU","image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/fa/Domo_Genesis-The_Alchemist-No_Idols.jpg/220px-Domo_Genesis-The_Alchemist-No_Idols.jpg","producers":"Alchemist","label":"Self Released","artist":"Domo Genesis","song_title":"Elimination Chamber  (featuring Earl Sweatshirt, Vince Staples & Action Bronson)","__v":0},{"_id":"58219ae58e7a590871b38894","listen_url":"https://soundcloud.com/defjam/frank-ocean-super-rich-kids","image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f5/Super_Rich_Kids.jpg/220px-Super_Rich_Kids.jpg","producers":"Malay","label":"Def Jam","artist":"Frank Ocean","song_title":"Super Rich Kids (featuring Earl Sweatshirt)","__v":0},{"_id":"58219c0a8e7a590871b38895","listen_url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FcDXL5Aw0o","image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Hive-earlsweat.jpg/220px-Hive-earlsweat.jpg","producers":"randomblackdude and Matt Martians","label":"Tan Cressida","artist":"Earl Sweatshirt","song_title":"Hive ( featuring Casey Veggies and Vince Staples)","__v":0},{"_id":"58219f3f8e7a590871b38896","listen_url":"https://vimeo.com/31781199","image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/2/2e/Frank-Ocean-Thinkin-Bout-You-2012.png/220px-Frank-Ocean-Thinkin-Bout-You-2012.png","producers":"Shea Taylor","label":"Def Jam","artist":"Frank Ocean","song_title":"Thinkin Bout You","__v":0},{"_id":"5821a3e88e7a590871b38897","listen_url":"https://vimeo.com/49091270","image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/71/Frankoceanpyramids.jpg/220px-Frankoceanpyramids.jpg","producers":"Frank Ocean, Malay and Om'Mas Keith","label":"Def Jam","artist":"Frank Ocean","song_title":"Pyramids","__v":0},{"_id":"582b4010b5a2eb460b850a2c","listen_url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCbWLSZrZfw","image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/81/Chum_Earl_Sweatshirt.jpg/220px-Chum_Earl_Sweatshirt.jpg","producers":"randomblackdude, Christian Rich & Hugo (Outro)","label":"Tan Cressida","artist":"Earl Sweatshirt","song_title":"Chum","__v":0}]}
```

Here is the AngularJS code, as you can see I am trying to create a loop that gets all the artist's names and their song title:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>



<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
    {{ x.artist + ', ' + x.song_title}}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://forgetthis-jafar70.c9users.io").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.data;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think you need to enable CORS to retrieve the data.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the API, or with AngularJS? Can you GET that URL in your browser? Can you GET it with jQuery (or any JavaScript you may be more familiar with)?

Comment: The error here is `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://forgetthis-jafar70.c9users.io/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`.  you should research CORS, and post the error when you post a question, so others don't have to recreate the error on your behalf.

Comment: @Claies thank you I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this after your module declaration:

```
app.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider) {
         $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', 'https://forgetthis-jafar70.c9users.io/**']);

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Claies I had to enable CORS. I had to add these few lines of code to my index.js file (nodejs).

```
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type')
    next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I am getting below error while requesting for the `API`.

> https://forgetthis-jafar70.c9users.io/ 503 (Service Unavailable)

So, I hardcoded the response in the controller :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [  
      {  
         "_id":"58175cb6f0c48b2b9821d799",
         "listen_url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSbZidsgMfw",
         "image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/41/Yonkers_tyler_cover.jpg/220px-  Yonkers_tyler_cover.jpg",
         "producers":"Tyler, The Creator",
         "label":"XL Recordings",
         "artist":"Tyler, The Creator",
         "song_title":"Yonkers ",
         "__v":0
      },
      {  
         "_id":"581760e7aa7eb70a8cf0d770",
         "listen_url":"https://vimeo.com/179791907",
         "image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2a/Frank_Ocean_Blonde_2.jpg",
         "producers":"Frank Ocean & Om'Mas Keith",
         "label":"Boys Don't Cry",
         "artist":"Frank Ocean",
         "song_title":"Nikes",
         "__v":0
      },
      {  
         "_id":"582199b38e7a590871b38893",
         "listen_url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4pon-hdEXU",
         "image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/fa/Domo_Genesis-The_Alchemist-No_Idols.jpg/220px-Domo_Genesis-The_Alchemist-No_Idols.jpg",
         "producers":"Alchemist",
         "label":"Self Released",
         "artist":"Domo Genesis",
         "song_title":"Elimination Chamber  (featuring Earl Sweatshirt, Vince Staples & Action Bronson)",
         "__v":0
      },
      {  
         "_id":"58219ae58e7a590871b38894",
         "listen_url":"https://soundcloud.com/defjam/frank-ocean-super-rich-kids",
         "image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f5/Super_Rich_Kids.jpg/220px-Super_Rich_Kids.jpg",
         "producers":"Malay",
         "label":"Def Jam",
         "artist":"Frank Ocean",
         "song_title":"Super Rich Kids (featuring Earl Sweatshirt)",
         "__v":0
      },
      {  
         "_id":"58219c0a8e7a590871b38895",
         "listen_url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FcDXL5Aw0o",
         "image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Hive-earlsweat.jpg/220px-Hive-earlsweat.jpg",
         "producers":"randomblackdude and Matt Martians",
         "label":"Tan Cressida",
         "artist":"Earl Sweatshirt",
         "song_title":"Hive ( featuring Casey Veggies and Vince Staples)",
         "__v":0
      },
      {  
         "_id":"58219f3f8e7a590871b38896",
         "listen_url":"https://vimeo.com/31781199",
         "image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/2/2e/Frank-Ocean-Thinkin-Bout-You-2012.png/220px-Frank-Ocean-Thinkin-Bout-You-2012.png",
         "producers":"Shea Taylor",
         "label":"Def Jam",
         "artist":"Frank Ocean",
         "song_title":"Thinkin Bout You",
         "__v":0
      },
      {  
         "_id":"5821a3e88e7a590871b38897",
         "listen_url":"https://vimeo.com/49091270",
         "image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/71/Frankoceanpyramids.jpg/220px-Frankoceanpyramids.jpg",
         "producers":"Frank Ocean, Malay and Om'Mas Keith",
         "label":"Def Jam",
         "artist":"Frank Ocean",
         "song_title":"Pyramids",
         "__v":0
      },
      {  
         "_id":"582b4010b5a2eb460b850a2c",
         "listen_url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCbWLSZrZfw",
         "image_url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/81/Chum_Earl_Sweatshirt.jpg/220px-Chum_Earl_Sweatshirt.jpg",
         "producers":"randomblackdude, Christian Rich & Hugo (Outro)",
         "label":"Tan Cressida",
         "artist":"Earl Sweatshirt",
         "song_title":"Chum",
         "__v":0
      }
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
    {{ x.artist + ', ' + x.song_title}}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```